# Flexible layout to cover the rest of the page and divide the height in half for children

Tags: html, css, layout

Here's a sample layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dynamic DIV</title>
    <style>
        #header {
            background: green;
        }
        #header * {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        button {
            float: right;
        }
        #top {
            background: yellow;
        }
        #bottom {
            background: aqua;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <label for="checker">Check</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checker">
        <label for="slider">Slider</label>
        <input type="range" id="slider"><span>Some text</span>
        <button type="button">Bar</button>
        <button type="button">Foo</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="top">Top content</div>
        <div id="bottom">Bottom content</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CZt36/1/

How can I extend the `content` DIV to he rest of the page so that the `top` and `bottom` DIVs get 50% of the `content` DIV height?

Note: I don't want to support old browsers or use JavaScript as mentioned in some similar posts.

Comment: I think you need flex layout.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do it and wonder if you'd mind providing a Fiddle or snippet.

Comment: I cant at the moment for I'm only on a mobile device

Answer (score 0):

`height:100%` means filling all the height of the parent element. In your case parent element of the content is `body`, so you need to make it 100% first; and then 100% to the patent oft that, i.e. `html`. Then give some height to the header like 10% and rest to the content so that it can occupy all the rest of the body and then 50% to the child elements of the content. Updated Fiddle is attached

Add this to your css

```
   #header
    {
        background:green;
        height:10%
    }

    html,body
    {
        height:100%;
        margin:0px;
    }

    #content
    {
        height:90%;
    }
    #top,#bottom
    {
       height:50%
    }
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CZt36/5/

Comment: It doubles the size of the page. The `content` div shouldn't exceed the rest of the page and create an extra scrollbar.

Comment: I have updated the answer with new fiddle. Now it is working fine

Comment: Still the extra scrollbar. :(

Comment: Do you have a fix header footer size?

Comment: Without any header height I cannot think of answer as of now.You can give some header height like 10% and rest to the content 90%. Checkout the new fiddle.